# How can I improve the accuracy of multiclass Random forest classifier for categorical variables?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I am running a Random forest multiclass classification model. My current accuracy is 57%.
How can I improve it?
Following are the details

1. All 4 features are categorical variables
2. After encoding these 4 features generated overall 92 columns
   3.I have taken care of feature scaling using Robust scaler
   4.I have run Random forest classifier with 10 and 100 decision trees. Accuracy scores are 57.05 and 57.28 respectively
   5.Then I have sorted based on Feature importance and removed the least scored ones
3. Accuracy is improved only to 57.35%.

Classification report shown below

```
          **precision    recall   f1-score   support**

     0.0       0.42      0.35      0.38       666
     1.0       0.53      0.30      0.39       280
     2.0       0.63      0.82      0.71      1552
     3.0       0.45      0.20      0.28       426

accuracy                           0.57      2924
```

How can I improve the accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross fold validation or tuning the data for better accuracy result.